# Counting rows and displaying it on my view

Tags: laravel

I have a table that contain some projects. I need to display the total number of projects which are in the database to my view.

**View**:

```
<div class="text">TOTAL PROJECTS</div>
    @foreach($project_counts as $project_count)
        {{$project_count->id}}
    @endforeach
```

**Controller**:

```
$project_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) from projects";

return view('layouts.songwe.projects.index')->with('project_count',$project_count);
```

Comment: spelling error here:  @foreach($projcet_counts as $project_count)

Comment: What is the question and why are you querying in a view file?

Comment: I am a learner to laravel and i have created a small project and i want it to display the number of project inserted into a DB to my index.blade

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call a query in your view, do this in your controller and then send back to the view, like this:

*I will consider that you have a model name Project*

**Controller**

```
$projects = Project::all()->count();
 return view('layouts.songwe.projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

**View**

```
<div class="text">TOTAL PROJECTS</div>
{{$projects}}
```

Comment: thanks Lucas I did as you said how to i call it from my index.blade

Comment: I wrote this in my index.blade @foreach($projects as $project)
                                {{$project->count()}}
                                @endforeach

Comment: the next time you should say which file you are showing, you have mixed the code of the view with that of the controller

Comment: In your view you could print the variable using this:: {{ $projects }}

Comment: Thanks Lucas i have problem fixed

Comment: i'm glad to help :). Please accept this answer (check button).